# Conditional $match MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongo Queries and I can't really get this bit to work.

I have a query where I am trying to execute a part where I need to check for a variable and then match.

```
const FIRST_SUBJECT = keywords_list[0].subjects || {"$ne":null};

.
.
.

{'$match': {'entities.qcode': FIRST_SUBJECT}},
```

In the above, I want to execute the $match only if `FIRST_SUBJECT` is not empty or null.

I have tried a `$cond` inside the `$match` and vice-a-versa but they both throw errors

In simple terms :

```
if(FIRST_SUBJECT)
$match
else
skip $match
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you mean if `keywords_list[0].subjects` is not empty or null, because `FIRST_SUBJECT ` will never be empty or null

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Need to use `or`

```
   $match: {
      $or : [
       { "entities.qcode" : keywords_list[0].subjects} ,
       { "entities.qcode" : {$ne:null} }
    ]}
```